# Locking Order of table with foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, h2, hsqldb

If I create a schema such as the following:

```
create table org 
( 
    org_id bigint not null auto_increment, 
    name varchar(255) not null, 
    primary key(org_id)
);

create table user 
( 
    user_id bigint not null auto_increment, 
    name varchar(255) not null, 
    org_id bigint not null, 

    primary key(user_id), 
    foreign key(org_id) references org (org_id)
);
```

Where the org table has one entry:

```
insert into org (name) values ('org 1');
```

If I run the following sql statement:

```
insert into user (name, org_id) values ('user 1', 1);
```

In what order will the tables be locked? Is it deterministic? What if there were a second foreign key constraint to another table?

Comment: I think only one table gets locked for an insert onto a given table (assuming the table has no triggers).

Comment: When you do an INSERT, exclusive record-level locks are usually placed on a table being inserted into. There would be shared locks placed on tables which have foreign key relations i.e. are master-tables of the table being inserted to